# UIView should be transparent but only shows white

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller, transparency

I have a `UIViewController` which contains a label and button. I would like the background of the view to be transparent so I set it to `clearColor` and `opaque = NO`.

However, the view always displays a white background. How can I fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: What is behind the view?

Comment: Seconded. Maybe it is transparent, and the white background you're seeing is whatever's behind it. What's probably happening is that you're seeing the UIWindow's background (note: not the UIViewController's), which, IIRC, defaults to white.

Comment: Behind the view is a table view. Its the view controller background because if i change it to yellow then it changes appropriately. Just cant seem to set it to transparent.

Comment: Is it because i am using `presentModalViewController`? I am using that because i dont want users to be able to interact with my table view until they dismiss this custom view...

Comment: It is not possible. Once the view is pushed to the top, whatever is behind it gets hidden so your top view will adjust its alpha but there's nothing behind it to be displayed (so you will see white).

Comment: When i use addSubview i can make it transparent.

Answer (score 2):

Once a new view controller is pushed to the top of the stack, whatever is behind it gets hidden so you can adjust the alpha settings for that view but there's nothing to reveal behind it (so you will see white).

You need to use a UIView instead. I'd normally subclass UIView and customise it the way I want, then instantiate and add it as a subview whenever you need to use it:

```
-(id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{    
    if (self = [super initWithFrame:CGRectZero])
    {
       // Add your label and button here...
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: That doesn't sound right. A UIViewController uses a UIView anyways, so it shouldn't matter if you're using one or the other.

Comment: Have you tried? Let me know if you managed to accomplish this without using a UIView.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I do not have enough rep to comment on Rog's answer, so I will post 'Another Answer'.

Try this code and see if it turns out well for you:

```
UIVIew *view = [[UIView alloc] init];
view.alpha = 0; // alpha 1.0 is opaque, alpha 0.5 is translucent and 0 is clear
```

Honestly, I have not tried that before as I do not require doing so. But when I drag a new UIView from the library, alpha option is in the properties.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This should work but be aware that the designated initialiser for UIView is actually initWithFrame: